# How to mock i18next and react-i18next for testing a component/view using typescript

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I basically have a react website and I'm using typescript for both the source and test code. I have integrated the i18next and react-i18next libraries to my project for supporting translations and modified one of my react components. However, I'm having issues when I try to unit test my components that are extending withTranslation. The first problem i'm having is i'm getting a compilation error, saying that my props are missing: i18n, tReady and t. And yes that is true they are not there, but I'm not sure how should I handle that.

I have tried including the mock below on my tests, which would supposedly pass the required props to my component:

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    withTranslation: () => (Component: any) => {
        Component.defaultProps = {
            ...Component.defaultProps,
            t: () => "",
        };
        return Component;
    },
}));
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
interface DemoViewProps extends WithTranslation {
name: string;
}
```

```
const DemoView = (props: DemoViewProps) => {
const { t, name } = props;
return <div>{t("string id")} {name}</div>
}
This is how my test code looks like:

describe("<DemoView>", () => {
const props = {
name: "NAME",
};
const component = shallow(<DemoView {...props} />);
it("should do something", () => {
...some testing here
});
});
```

I would like not to get compilation errors and be able to run my unit tests. I would also like my code not to become to cumbersome, since I will be doing this across different components that are using withTranslation()

Comment: Did u sort it out?